# Rails 5 logger spec expect.to have_received - received: 0 times error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Inside my Rails 5 app I've got an integration specs where in case of passing failure params it should log that error by executing the `log_error` module method. Like below:

```
# appointments_controller.rb
def create
  (...)
  if failure_appointments.any?
    log_error(appointments_errors.join(', '))
  else
    success_response(succeeded_appointments)
  end
end

# lib/my_app_logger.rb
module MyAppLogger
  module_function

  def log_error(message)  
    Logger.new($stdout).error(message)
  end
end
```

I've prepared `appointments_controller_specs.rb`

context 'with invalid data' do
subject { post('/api/import', params: file_fixture('invalid_import_data.json').read, headers: { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json' }) }

```
it 'logs the error' do
  allow(MyAppLogger).to receive(:log_error)
  subject

  expect(MyAppLogger).to have_received(:log_error).with("Registration number can't be blank")
end
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(MyAppLogger).to have_received(:log_error).with("Car registration number can't be blank")

   (MyAppLogger).log_error("Registration number can't be blank")
       expected: 1 time with arguments: ("Registration number can't be blank")
       received: 0 times
```

What did I missed?

I've tried to change `environments/test.rb` like described in few topics to:

```
  # Enable stdout logger
  config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

  # Set log level
  config.log_level = :ERROR
```

or

```
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
```

But it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Do you really need to use a spy here? Why not just use `expect(MyAppLogger).to receive(:log_error).with(...); subject`. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/basics/expecting-messages

Comment: @max I've tried  `dbl = double(MyAppLogger); expect(dbl).to receive(:log_error).with("Registration number can't be blank"); subject` and also `allow(MyAppLogger).to receive(:log_error) (...)`  but I'm getting the old same error (`expected: 1, received: 0`)  in both cases.

Comment: You probally should not be using `subject` like that. The block is actually called implicitly when setting up the example and might actually be memoizing the response.  Using `subject` explicitly is also somewhat of a code smell. http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/blog/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/

Comment: Instead you can use `let(:do_the_action){ ... }`.

Comment: For reasons unknown to me, after 6 hours the tests passed. I didn't even change a line of code, just use your first suggestion - that's odd.